# Using vb.net; How do I listen for a scroll event in a scrollable panel?

Tags: vb.net, scroll, eventhandler

I'm simply trying to add a handler for when the panel has been scrolled and I can't seem to find any info on it.

I've added a handler for the .scroll event, but that only works when you actually use the scroll bar. If the panel scrolls with the mouse wheel, then the event is not fired.

Comment: Yes. It is winforms VS 2012.

Comment: There's also a `MouseWheel` event...

Comment: @Idle_Mind I know about the mousewheel event. I am using it. That's the problem. Read the question.

Comment: I did read your question.  It states that the `Scroll` event does not fire when you use the mouse wheel.  My suggestion is to use the `MouseWheel` event as well as the `Scroll` event.  Perhaps you should re-read **your** question to see what you actually said?

Comment: @User2721815 If you posted your code, it would help avoid these little misunderstandings too.

Comment: @Idle_Mind You are correct. I'm not too proud to admit when I am wrong. I apologize for my abrupt reply. I assumed that since I was already listening for the scroll event that it would also recognize when the wheel was used to scroll the panel, but it wasn't. So now I am using both listeners (.scroll and .mousewheel) to cover both scenarios and it seems to work fine. Post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the `Scroll` event, use the `MouseWheel`event to trap scrolling as a result of using the mouse wheel.